# Convert SrtingSet to String

Tags: python, string, set

I want to convert stringset into string using python3.

Input = "{'abc','def'}"

I have tried all the possibilities I can thing of such as eval, literal_eval and conversion into set etc. But I a not able to figure out the solution.

Solution and explanation will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What result are you looking for?  `('abc','def')`?

Comment: Hey, I am looking for list of string. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do the conversion inside the `eval` call:

```
inp = "{'abc','def'}"
lst = eval("list(" + inp + ")")  # eval("list({'abc','def'})")
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['def', 'abc']
```

The order changed because the original string is a unordered set. To maintain the order, you need to swap the brackets:

```
inp = "{'abc','def'}"
lst = eval("[" + inp[1:-1] +"]")  # eval("['abc','def']")
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['abc', 'def']
```

If you want to use `ast.literal_eval` instead of `eval`, try this code:

```
# read as set
inp = "{'abc','def'}"
lst = list(ast.literal_eval(inp))  # ast.literal_eval("{'abc','def'}")
print(lst)  # ['abc', 'def']
```

---

```
# read as list  
inp = "{'abc','def'}"
lst = list(ast.literal_eval("[" + inp[1:-1] +"]"))  # ast.literal_eval("['abc','def']")
print(lst)  # ['abc', 'def']
```

Note that eval returned the first result in the wrong order while `literal_eval` returned it in the same order as the string.

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate your answer

Comment: is there a way, I can use as.literal_eval in this example, since pep8 encourages use of ast.literal_eval instal of eval because it is not the safe method.

Comment: Amazing job Mike.